# How to speed up an sql query with no index in the table and without having to redeploy the project

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

We have SQL code in a Java Web App that is making a query but is not using an index and the queries are taking 10+ seconds, locking up connection pools, etc.

The problem is that the column in the table is a `varchar2` but the query is passing the parameter as a number (it is missing the quotes).  The fix is trivial to make and if it were not for business reasons that we cannot do a redeploy. So we are stuck with the code as we cannot redeploy the whole project.

Here are some possible approaches to solve this issue, Any other ideas or comments on these?

- Is there some voodoo we can do on the Oracle side to convince it to use the index anyway?
- Maybe altering the table in some way.
- Create a fix without deploying the war file(s)?

Comment: I got angry just by reading that..) Easiest is to change the query

Comment: `"The fix is trivial to make and if it were not for business reasons that we cannot do a redeploy."` - This sounds like an XY problem.  If the solution is trivial but something else is in the way, then fix the something else.  Fix the *actual problem*, instead of inventing *another problem* just to *hide* the actual problem.

Comment: If you go to the doctor and he say `take this pill and you feel better`, will you reply `I dont like pills, can I rest until get better instead?` Just fix that thing. Btw How you release a software with 10s response time? Someone test it?

Comment: Are you saying there isn't an index, or there is an index and it isn't being used, or there are several indexes and it's using the wrong one? Are you filtering on multiple conditions? Sounds like you're getting lucky avoiding an ORA-01722; how sure are you that using quotes will actually fix it? (And why are you passing hard-coded values at all; and why would the business block a redeploy but let you alter a table definition?)

Comment: I feel your pain.  We are in a government mandated lock down of the code.  Doing the right thing is not an option for the duration.

Answer (score 2):

Change the column in the table to be a number (if you can pass it as a number in the query then it must be a number data type). If you can't pass it in as a number then it's impossible anyway as it will be an invalid query as soon as someone enters a string.

This will let you use the index and by considerably faster on top of that.

Incidentally your description worries me - it sounds like you might be vulnerable to an SQL injection attack, how are you setting these values into the query?

Comment: The column in question also contains string data, it is just that the query passes a number.

Comment: Unless you can move the string data to a separate column then you're out of luck.

Comment: It must be using some other index then, because Oracle would be doing an implicit type conversion of your character field into a number.  If Oracle were doing a full table scan, it would fail with `ORA-1722 Invalid number` as soon as it looked at a record with a non-numeric value.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak If it's using some other index, then that wouldn't cause the 10s delay right?

Comment: @uhsarp - depends which index, and why it's choosing to use it, and how selective it is. Have you looked at the execution plan to see what it's actually doing? Are your stats up to date?

Comment: @uhsarp If only that were true!  Unfortunately, a query can use an index and still take 10 seconds to run.

Comment: We were able to add a Function based index  and the query improved immediately.